# jQuery selector string + dynamic variable

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I want to get URL parameters and extract last param from:

```
http://localhost/projecct/Menus/page/8
```

This gives me `8`:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
var pid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // this gives 8
var currentMenu=('menu'+pid);                      //this gives menu8
alert($('.'+currentMenu).html());                  //but this give me null 
//the above line is where I stucked
```

I want to make CSS property `display:block` for the parent all `ul`s selected with:

```
$('.'+currentMenu).parents("ul").css({'display':'block'});
```

HTML:

```
  <ul>
     <li class='menu1'>
        <a href='#'>Menu1</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='menu11'>
               <a href='#'>Menu11</a>
               <ul>....</ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>

     <li class='menu2'>
        <a href='#'>Menu2</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='menu21'>
               <a href='#'>Menu21</a>
               <ul>....</ul>
           </li>
           <li class='menu22'>
               <a href='#'>Menu22</a>
               <ul>....</ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>

     <li class='menu3'>
        ..........
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the HTML looks like?

Comment: alert `$('.'+ currentMenu).length` and tell what you get.

Comment: Without seeing some of the HTML, how are we supposed to know why your selector fails to find an element ?

Comment: And I just have to note that you could do `$('.' + window.location.href.split('/').pop()).closest('ul').show()`

Comment: If you're getting null, it means there's no `class="menu8"` on the page.

Comment: @adeneo Just because you could, doesn't mean you _should_. :)

Comment: @Barmar - The point was really to get the `href` property of the `location` object instead of calling `toString()` on it, and then split on `/` and pop of the last one, and you really *should* do that.

Comment: alert $('.'+ currentMenu).length returns 0

Comment: @user3813434 There's your problem. You're targeting an element that doesn't yet exist. Where is the script block in relation to the HTML (i.e. in the `<head>` or in the `<body>`)?

Comment: create a demo on jsFiddle to show us what you have, as the javascript and/or the css for the menu would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *as of when that code runs*, there is no `.menu8` element on the page. This could be because it doesn't exist *yet*, or because you never put one on the page at all.

If this code is running on page load, and you do define an element with the class `menu8` in the HTML, move that code into a `script` tag at the bottom of the page, after all your DOM elements have been defined, so that they'll be there when the code runs.

E.g., this will fail:

```
<script src="yourcode.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<li class="menu8"></li>
```

but this will work:

```
<li class="menu8"></li>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="yourcode.js"></script>
```

This is one reason that the usual recommendation is that unless you have some strong reason to do otherwise, put your scripts at the bottom of the page, immediately before the closing `</body>` tag.

(If your code adds the `.menu8` element later, then you'll have to run your code using it *after* it has been added.)

If you don't have control over where the `script` elements go, then you can wrap your code in a "ready" handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

or the shortcut version of it:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

But if you control where the `script` tags go, there's no need.

Comment: I have already did that, I placed js code at end of page, but I think I have problem with selector bcz alert $('.'+ currentMenu).length returns 0, that means no object selected

Comment: @user3813434: The selector is fine, provided you really are trying to find an element with the class `menu8`. That element has to be on the page as of when the `$()` function trying to find it runs. If it is, and the script runs after that element exists, it works: http://jsbin.com/namavewi/1